# pass data between two web apis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have two webapi which are deployed on same server and I want to consume webapi #1 in webapi#2 , what is best practice to use in this regard -

Ex: Endpoints as follows for both apis
**http://servername/webapi1/GetUserInfo
http://servername/webapi2/testGetMethod**

now from webapi2 i want to call webapi1 GetUserInfo method to get all values for give user?

Comment: Have you looked at `HttpClient` or similar? Server code can call API just like client code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Httpclient` for this.You can try something like this -

```
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http://servername/webapi1/GetUserInfo");
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = baseAddress})
    {
        using (var response = httpClient.GetAsync(userName).Result)
        {
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                trackingResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
```